# How to left-align faceted-plots with patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, patchwork

I have two `facet_wrap` plots that I want to combine vertically and left-align with patchwork. My problem is that the number of columns isn't equal between the two plots (like in the simple example included below).

Is there a way to left-align these plots with patchwork?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(patchwork)

plot_ls <- data.frame(var_a = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4)),
                 var_b = c(letters[1:5], letters[c(1:2, 4:5)]),
                 var_x = "a",
                 var_y = rnorm(9),
                 var_color = "b") %>%
  split(.$var_a) %>%
  imap(function(df.x, var_a.x) {
    ggplot(data = df.x) +
      geom_point(aes(x = var_x, y = var_y, color = var_color)) +
      facet_wrap(var_b ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 2) +
      ylab(var_a.x) +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 1,
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,1))
  })

# ...centered, not aligned to the left...
plot_ls[[1]] + plot_ls[[2]] +
         plot_layout(ncol = 1,
                     guides = 'collect') & 
         theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Comment: If you use the design argument to plot layout, you can, with some faffing with the width of the plot, get everything to line up. I tried `
layout <- c(
  area(1, 1, 1, 3),
  area(2, 1, 2, 2)
)` and then `plot_layout(design = layout,...`

Answer (score 0):

The issue may have to do with wanting to set `aspect.ratio = 1`, which [may not be possible with patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#fixed-aspect-plots-1) if I also want to control alignment and dimensions. I can left-align by removing `aspect.ratio = 1` and get close-to-aligned facets by tweaking the design (as per @RichardTelford's comment):

```
plot_ls <- data.frame(var_a = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4)),
                 var_b = c(letters[1:5], letters[c(1:2, 4:5)]),
                 var_x = "a",
                 var_y = rnorm(9),
                 var_color = "b") %>%
  split(.$var_a) %>%
  imap(function(df.x, var_a.x) {
    ggplot(data = df.x) +
      geom_point(aes(x = var_x, y = var_y, color = var_color)) +
      facet_wrap(var_b ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 2) +
      ylab(var_a.x) +
      theme(# aspect.ratio = 1,
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,1))
  })

# ...centered, not aligned to the left...
plot_ls[[1]] + plot_ls[[2]] +
         plot_layout(design = "
                         AAAAAA
                         BBBB##
                         ",
                     guides = 'collect') & 
         theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```