# Align bottom axes with patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, patchwork

My problem is similar to this one: [How to left-align faceted-plots with patchwork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138249/how-to-left-align-faceted-plots-with-patchwork). I'm trying to align the bottom axes in patchwork. My actual plot is a lot more complex than this MWE-- I've tried facet_wrap, ggarrange, and cowplot, and patchwork gets the closest to what I want by far. I'm so close to getting this right so any help would be really appreciated!

```
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

g1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sort(rnorm(100)), y = sort(rnorm(100)))) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
  coord_fixed()
g2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sort(rnorm(100)), y = 2*sort(rnorm(100)))) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, linetype = 'dashed') + 
  coord_fixed()
(g1 + g2) + plot_layout(widths = c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to have `coord_fixed()`?

Comment: If the coordinate ratio is fixed, but the two plots' data span different aspect ratios,  they will naturally have different widths at a given scale, but you want them equal width. I'm not sure what a solution would look like. What result do you expect? Is a solution possible within those constraints?

Comment: Yes, the coord_fixed() is mandatory. I would like to have either empty space above the left-hand plot or an extended y-axis on the left-hand plot.

Answer (score 0):

If `coord_fixed()` is removed, then it works fine with `ggarrange` function of `ggpubr` package

```
require(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

g1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sort(rnorm(100)), y = sort(rnorm(100)))) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, linetype = 'dashed') 

g2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = sort(rnorm(100)), y = 2*sort(rnorm(100)))) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, linetype = 'dashed') 

ggarrange(g1, g2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't remove coord_fixed(), and I have to use patchwork as stated above.